# How can I install Python 3.7 on an old centos shared web host (without root)?

Tags: python-3.x, centos

I want to install Python 3.7 on a web hosting server that is live (production) without disturbing anything.  I have SSH terminal access and I guess the server is running centos from the following commands:

```
> cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.10.0-693.11.6.1.ELK.el6.x86_64 (...) (gcc version 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15) (GCC) )
> rpm -qa centos-release
centos-release-6-10.el6.centos.12.3.x86_64
```

I tried to see what was installed with:

```
> rpm -qa | sort
...
Python27-2.7.8-1.x86_64
Python27-MySQL-1.2.3-2.el6.x86_64
Python27-bs4-4.1.3-1.noarch
Python27-distribute-0.6.32-1.noarch
Python27-lxml-3.0.1-1.x86_64
Python27-pip-1.2.1-1.noarch
Python27-regex-0.1.20120904-1.x86_64
Python27-virtualenv-1.8.4-1.noarch
Python3-3.2.3-1.x86_64
Python3-distribute-0.6.32-1.noarch
Python3-pip-1.2.1-1.noarch
Python3-virtualenv-1.8.4-1.noarch
...
```

So it looks like there's Python 2.7 and 3.2 already installed, and I don't want to disturb them.

I want to run a Python 3.7 script with dependencies on some modules.

**What is the safest way** of installing Python 3.7 (along with pip for modules) somewhere that will not mess with the current installation?

NOTE: I am familiar with conda/pip mostly on Windows, but I have limited knowledge of this linux environment.

**EDIT:** I first thought it was RHEL. I edited the post for centos.

**EDIT:** I have tried many unsuccessful attempts to install Python 3.7 on this shared web hosting:

#### Trying to create a virtualenv with Python 3.2:

```
> python3 -m virtualenv my_isolated_py3

New python executable in my_isolated_py3/bin/python3
Also creating executable in my_isolated_py3/bin/python
Installing distribute.....................
  Complete output from command /home2/cccccc/my_isolated_py3/bin/python3 -c "#!python
\"\"\"Bootstra...   sys.exit(main())
":
  Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.31.tar.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 541, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 537, in main
  File "<string>", line 201, in download_setuptools
  File "/opt/python3/lib/python3.2/urllib/request.py", line 138, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/opt/python3/lib/python3.2/urllib/request.py", line 375, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/opt/python3/lib/python3.2/urllib/request.py", line 487, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/opt/python3/lib/python3.2/urllib/request.py", line 413, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/opt/python3/lib/python3.2/urllib/request.py", line 347, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/opt/python3/lib/python3.2/urllib/request.py", line 495, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: SSL is required
----------------------------------------
...Installing distribute...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python3/lib/python3.2/runpy.py", line 160, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/opt/python3/lib/python3.2/runpy.py", line 73, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/opt/python3/lib/python3.2/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2560, in <module>
    main()
  File "/opt/python3/lib/python3.2/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 964, in main
    never_download=options.never_download)
  File "/opt/python3/lib/python3.2/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1071, in create_environment
    search_dirs=search_dirs, never_download=never_download)
  File "/opt/python3/lib/python3.2/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 616, in install_distribute
    search_dirs=search_dirs, never_download=never_download)
  File "/opt/python3/lib/python3.2/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 583, in _install_req
    cwd=cwd)
  File "/opt/python3/lib/python3.2/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1042, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /home2/cccccc/my_isolated_py3/bin/python3 -c "#!python
\"\"\"Bootstra...   sys.exit(main())
" failed with error code 1
```

The key error is **urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: SSL is required**, which seems related to old non-https repository.

#### Trying to create a virtualenv with Python 2.6:

```
> python -m virtualenv my_isolated_py2

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/runpy.py", line 122, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/runpy.py", line 34, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2352, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 825, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 985, in create_environment
    site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear, symlink=symlink))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1179, in install_python
    copyfile(join(stdlib_dir, fn), join(lib_dir, fn), symlink)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 479, in copyfile
    copyfileordir(src, dest, symlink)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 454, in copyfileordir
    shutil.copytree(src, dest, symlink)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/shutil.py", line 173, in copytree
    raise Error, errors
shutil.Error: [('/usr/lib64/python2.6/config/libpython2.6.so', 'my_isolated_py2/lib/python2.6/config/libpython2.6.so', '[Errno 2] No such file or directory')]
```

#### Trying to install Python 3.7 miniconda:

```
> wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh

https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
Resolving repo.anaconda.com... 104.16.130.3, 104.16.131.3, 2606:4700::6810:8203, ...
Connecting to repo.anaconda.com|104.16.130.3|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 85055499 (81M) [application/x-sh]
Saving to: `Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh'

100%[=========================================>] 85,055,499   108M/s   in 0.8s

2020-06-11 08:22:53 (108 MB/s) - `Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh' saved [85055499/85055499]

> bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh

...
Unpacking payload ...
Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh: line 409: /home2/cccccc/miniconda3/preconda.tar.bz2: No such file or directory
```

#### Trying to install Python 3.7 from sources:

```
> wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.3/Python-3.7.3.tgz
> tar xvzf Python-3.7.3.tgz
> cd Python-3.7.3
> ./configure --prefix=$HOME/python_37

checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for python3.7... no
checking for python3... python3
checking for --enable-universalsdk... no
checking for --with-universal-archs... no
checking MACHDEP... checking for --without-gcc... no
checking for --with-icc... no
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in '/home2/cccccc/Python-3.7.3':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details
```

#### Trying to install Python 3.7 portable binaries:

```
> wget https://github.com/indygreg/python-build-standalone/releases/download/20200408/cpython-3.7.7-linux64-20200409T0045.tar.zst
> [unzstd on another machine since not installed here]
> tar -xvf cpython-3.7.7-linux64-20200409T0045.tar
...
tar: python/install/share/man/man1/python3.1: Cannot create symlink to `python3.7.1': No such file or directory
...
> ./python/install/bin/python3.7m
./python/install/bin/python3.7m: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.13' not found (required by ./python/install/bin/python3.7m)
```

I also found out that this shared web hosting greatly limits what we can do through terminal, which is **jailshell**.

Do I have any options left to use Python 3.7 on this machine?

Comment: The `el6` in `.el6.x86_6` indicates that this is RHEL 6. 4.8 is the version of gcc, which is the compiler used to build the kennel. Look at `/etc/redhat-release` for more information.

Comment: @omajid, Thanks for the cue.  However there is no such ```/etc/redhat-release``` on the server.  It might actually be a centos since ```rpm -qc centos-release``` returned ```centos-release-6-10.el6.centos.12.3.x86_64```.  I will edit the post.

Comment: This is ten years old operating system. It will be EOLed by November 2020. You should not put anything new on that.

Comment: Have you tried installing the virtual environment using something like "virtualenv -p /home/username/opt/python-2.7.15/bin/python venv".  This is from the below url. Beware of the security implications of doing this as others also pointed out.  Please see: https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215489338-Installing-and-using-virtualenv-with-Python-2

Comment: @C. Pappy, your suggestion actually works, but only for Python version that are already installed on the system.  I however cannot find a way of installing a new python version (3.7) within a virtualenv, with the limited privileges of this shared hosting (see my detailed unsuccessful attempts in my edited post).

Answer (score 2):

You can use venv to completely isolate your python environment from all other python versions (and python libraries) installed in the system.

Read the virtual environment, venv, docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html).

Comment: you are probably right if it was not limited by this shared web hosting constraints.  I edited the post with my unsuccessful attempts.